# add to array from a loop C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops, foreach

How can I add to an array which is in a foreach loop.

pseudo example

```cs
String[] mylist;

foreach ( ipadress ip in list )
{
    // I want to add to array ip.ToString();
}
// then put my list to a textbox
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using linq try this instead :

```
String[] mylist = list.Select(I => Convert.ToString(I.ip)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, if this is a homework problem, it should really be tagged as such.

Anyway, assuming you have complete control of the string[] you are passing values to, and assuming your ipaddress class has .ToString() overloaded to give you back some intelligent information:

```
string[] myList = new string[list.Count];
int i = 0;
foreach (IPAddress ip in list)
{
    myList[i++] = ip.ToString();
}
```

Although I have to question why you are going back and forth between arrays and list objects to begin with.

Comment: i am figureing out cod to show my local ip address. I posted it down. Although inside the foreach i made an if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork") that wil show me the ip, i realised that beeing new to c# don't know how to add array`s from loop. So i did that just for learning.

Comment: And don't laugh at "ip.AdressFamily.ToString()" :)) i did not knew to do this the hard way, and did not want to research

Comment: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: Oops. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: @Ramhound - Have you tried compiling it? The assumption is that 'ipaddress' is a fully fleshed-out class, and that 'list' is a List<ipaddress> object. It compiles just fine on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and short:

```
 String[] myList;

 List<int> intList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

 myList = intList.ConvertAll<String>(p => p.ToString()).ToArray<String>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out...new to programming.., thanks to all. I used same code that tharindlaksh posted.

this is how it looks:

```
string[] all ;
int i = 0;

foreach (IPAddres ip in host.AddressList)
{
     all[i] = ip.ToString();
     i++;
}

textBoxMain.Text = all[0] + "\n" + all[1] + \n" + all[2] + "\n" + all[3];
```

Comment: This code will not compile.  The correct class name is `IPAddress`.  Its not clear the reason you are converting the contents of `AddressList` to a string.

Comment: Don't forget to initialize your string[]! You'll want to set its length to (at least) match the length of the data you are passing in, or you risk getting out of bound exceptions.

Answer (score -2):

```
int i=0;
String[] mylist;
foreach(ipaddress ip in list)
{
mylist[i]=ip.ToString();
i++
}
```

Comment: Code that compiles is possible here.

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for! I figured it out by myself tho.. I tought that if i give an int i =0; out the loop and a i++ in the loop, at each loop it wil give i the value 0 .... New to c# :D

Comment: I just wrote this.. i imageine that the class is not Predefined one.. The idea was that.. Sorry if this code is not working..

Comment: It wasn't clear from the question, but it turns out there is a predefined IPAddress class in System.Net.
@Ramhound - Posting "This won't compile" and downvoting everything without explaining why it won't compile is not helpful to anyone.

Comment: That's right mate.. We are begginers of this field.. thank you for comment.. :D